# Redefine route in routes.php laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to change for name of my url in the route. However, after changing it to the new naming, I still can access my page using the old url. I've tried `route::delete` but it is not working. Using CMD php artisan route, I can still see my old route inside. How do I update it to a new url ? Help!!

From this:

```
Route::get('form/(:any?)', 'FormController@getform');
```

To this:

```
Route::get('createform/(:any?)', 'FormController@getform');
```

Thank you

Comment: Only the routes that are coded should be actionable, once they've been deleted or modified from your code they won't exist any more.  Are you sure you don't have any other routes to `form`?  Perhaps a `Route::controller`, `Route::resource`, or other wildcard route?

Comment: Yes I had Route::controller in place just now and due to that i am still able to go to my old url. But, even if i remove Route::controller, Route::get('createform/(:any?)', 'FormController@getform'); doesnt work too. Is there anything i miss out?